# Add a glyphicon even if i use Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, glyphicons

Hi  I'd like to know how can i add a glyphicon to the left of "input" in my code because I'm using django and I have to use forms.py you know.

My HTML code :

```
<form methode="post" action="/connexion" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off">Connexion</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

forms.py :

```
class ConnexionForm(forms.Form):

user = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Nom d'utilisateur"}))
password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: Use [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks you but I don't understand how i can add glyphicons with that

Comment: If adding the icon is all you want, render each form field individual and add a html element before the form. like `<i class="glyph..."></i> {{form.name}} ...`

Comment: @Beno if you know how to add glyphicons to a manually built html form, then all you're missing to do it with a django form is how to take hand on the form's rendering to get the desired html, which is what this article explains (in complement of the official documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just render fields manually instead of rendering the whole form, like:

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <i class="glyphicon..."></> {{ form.field_name }}
    ...
</form>
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Comment: Mmh.. Intersting ! I think it solves my problem ! I'll try that ! Thaaaaanks